# alexa sdk custom logic to determine if slot is required

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

i have an intent with two slots: 1 custom slot called "name" and one called "number" of type AMAZON.NUMBER.
Now for some names the number is required and for others it isn't.
How can i make alexa ask for the number if one of those names is given without a number?
Can i use the CanFulFillIntentRequest for that?
If so, all the sites about it say that i have to enable it under interfaces, but i can't find it there. Has it been removed?
btw, i'm using alexa sdk v2 for node.js in my lambda function

Answer (score 0):

If you CanFulFillIntentRequest for both slots the intent will hit lamdba only if 2 slots are filled.You can make CanFulFillIntentRequest for necessary one (name) and in the backend(lambda) you can check for number.If name that requires number is required give necessary response for number.

Comment: and how do make alexa send the CanFulFillIntentRequest? I can#t find the option anywhere

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this that can be updated without having to change the code is:

- Create a JSON with the names that are required to have a number and store it in S3.
- Make your Lambda function to retrieve it.
- Make your Lambda function check the value of the Name Slot is among those in the JSON or not.

  - If so, then take control of the Dialog then. I strongly suggest you to check [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html)
  - If not, then just continue.

Seems a bit complex mostly because of taking control of the dialog yourself. The other option is making the number required and let Alexa do the Dialog Management the thing is what to do when the number is not required.

If you know which names are required to have a number I would use a different slot for those and make the number required and let Alexa do the dialog management, the downside of this solution is that you will need to update manually those names (or use Bulk operations).

I think any of those 2 solutions can workout.

I hope you find this useful.